# List comprehension for 7x7 board

Tags: haskell

I have a 7x7 board and I want to select some elements from it. The elements I want to select are marked `o`, the other ones are marked `x`.

Here is the board:

```
xoxoxox
ooooooo
xooooox
ooooooo
xooooox
ooooooo
xoxoxox
```

I use indexing starting from 1. The point `(1,1)` is the top left.

The current list comprehension I have to select the `o`-elements is the following:

```
[(r,c) | r<-[1..7], c<-[1..7],
         (not (even r) && not (even c) && r/=1 && r/=7 && c/=1 && c/=7) 
         || even r
         || even c]
```

I am wondering if I can make this list comprehension more simple. The code above is in Haskell, however, pseudo-code or Python list comprehensions are also fine with me.

Answer (score 4):

Since 7 is prime, the following pseudo code works, although it involves some “thinking around the corner”.

```
[(r,c) | r<-[1..7], c<-[1..7], r * c not in [1, 3, 5, 7, 21, 35, 49]]
```

A more straightforward way would be

```
(r /= 1 && r /= 7 && c /= 1 && c /= 7) || even r || even c
```

Comment: The first solution generates the correct result. The second one still includes the `x`s on the first and last row.